# PHP preg_replace replace all www with http://www

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I replace all www occurrences with in a sentence with http://www ? The condition is if the matched www already have http:// prefix there is no need to replace.

For better understanding:

```
<a href="www.test.com">test</a> should be <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>

<a href="http://www.test.com">test</a> also should be <a href="http://www.test.com">test</a>
```

Comment: As another way to think about it, would there always be a space before a "www"?

Comment: @ChrisForrence no space.

Comment: @ChrisForrence question updated.

Comment: @SujathanR: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522727/2102956) with your [sample data](https://regex101.com/r/mOwA5B/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this positive look ahead `(?=www)` to mark the point just before a `www` and use this negative look behind `(?<!http:\/\/)` to mark the point that is not preceded by `http://` and insert `http://` at that point.

```
(?<!http:\/\/)(?=www)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mOwA5B/1)**